# Password Validator

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I'm currently trying to make a password validator work with boolean method, since the teacher asked us to do so. This is driving me nuts. To be correct, the password need to have one uppercase, one lower case letter, at least 10 characters and one number. I'm aware that right now, my method returns entirely with the value false, but I'm wondering how I can break the code once I have one uppercase, or one lowercase.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
public class AtLeast1UppercaseLowercaseNumber {

public static void main(String[] args){
String password = "H";
System.out.println(password);
if(isSecurePassword(password)){
  System.out.println("Yay it works");}
else {
  System.out.println("you suck");}
}

public static isSecurePassword(String password) {
int uppercase = 0, lowercase = 0, number = 0;

 for(int i=0; i<password.length(); i++) {   
  for(char c ='A'; c <='Z'; c++) {        
    if(password.charAt(i) == c) {
      uppercase++;

      if( uppercase >= 1) {

  for(char t = 'a'; t <='z'; t++) {   
    if(password.charAt(i) == t) {
      lowercase++;
      if(lowercase >= 1) {

      }
    }
  }


  for(int j = '0'; j <='9'; j++) {
    if(password.charAt(i) == j) {
      number++;
      if( number >= 1) {

      }
    }
      }
  }
  return false;
  }
  }
```

Comment: This isn't really a place to get help with homework. Have you looked at other ways to work with strings, to check for the contents and length? Think about wether many loops are really the right approach (and how complex it makes it to understand). Also, be specific with requirements and your description of the problem when you ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start by creating multiple `private` and `static` test methods, and then *delegate* to them in your `public` `isSecurePassword(String)` method. Implement test methods like `boolean oneUpper(String)`, `boolean oneLower(String)`, `boolean oneDigit(String)` and `boolean tenCharacters(String)` as an example

```
private static boolean tenCharacters(String str) {
    return str.length() > 9;
}
```

and a second example

```
private static boolean oneUpper(String str) {
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then your `isSecurePassword(String)` is just

```
public static boolean isSecurePassword(String str) {
    return tenCharacters(str) && oneUpper(str) && oneLower(str)
            && oneDigit(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i created the other methods, but the program is telling me that he can't find Character. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Suligane [`java.lang.Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) is in the `java.lang` package.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one return in this method, which explicitly returns false, this method will always return false.

Method 1:
Define a boolean, which will be returned in the last statement of the method. This boolean is true by default and will be set false if one condition is wrong.

Method 2:
The last statement is an implicit return true statement, and whenever a condition is not fullfilled return false. This will prevent the method from executing more tests.

Method 3:
Make the method look like this

```
if (containsUpperCase(string) && contains...)
    return true;
return false;
```